# jquery using find and addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class (errorPopup) styled in my css using position:absolute which gets its data from a json file. i want to call upon this class only when there is an error.

```
<div class="parent">
  <input class="child" type="text">
</div>
```

in my javascript file i'm checking if input value is greater than data-max. if so, i use my errorPopup:

```
$('.child').parents('.parent').find('.errorPopup').addClass('active');
```

This doesn't seem to be working however. The parent has position:relative.

Comment: where is `.errorPopup` on html?

Comment: That code will only work if `.errorPopup` is inside `.parent`

Comment: error popup is in a CSS file

Comment: There should be an `.errorPopup` on the html. Your code is `find`ing it and cant find.

Comment: It's someone else's code they asked me to fix this part. They've implemented it using the same logic

Comment: But for the previous implementation the error popup isn't specifically written in the html

Comment: Is there error on the previous implementation?

Comment: No the previous implementations are all working fine

Comment: Can you check where the `.errorPopup` html on the previous implementation?

Comment: It's not in my parent class. it's nested inside some other class. so i copied it to my class. Still not working

Comment: Can you update your post with new the html after you copy it?

Comment: @Eddie I copied the CSS styling of error popup so it would come under the CSS styling of parent. In the previous implementations they didn't add the class to the html only used this to make it active

Answer (score 0):

You should have errorPopup class in your html. if you are using the jquery like this ,

```
$('.child').parents('.parent').find('.errorPopup').addClass('active');
```

then the HTML should be like

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="errorPopup">Please fill out it</div>
  <input class="child" type="text">
</div>
```

Note: by default .errorPopup in  CSS should be display:none and .errorPopup.active should be display:block.

Thanks !

Comment: This is not what I want. I understand how this works. The code i'm working on uses templating to bring this class in

Comment: @Nightshade Where does that `errorPopup` element comes into page's DOM after your templating engine code runs? Can you add the structure of required HTML elements? Possibility is that your `errorPopup` is appearing somewhere else in your page.

Comment: I figured it out. the templating wasn't done for my "parent" class.